# How to fully resolve axios/fetch call/promise before returning value?

Tags: javascript, fetch, axios, es6-promise

I have a function

```
function getData(foo) {
 return axios.get(url+foo)
  .then(response => response.baz)
  .catch(error => console.log(error))
}
```

Somewhere else in my code I call it.

```
function baz() {
  //....
  document.getElementById('bar').textContent = getData()
 //....
}
```

But then I end up with the text of `[object Promise]` inside my element.

Why does this happen and how can I make sure only the true value gets inserted without using async/await?

Comment: "*Why does this happen*" - because you are returning a promise from `getData()`. "*how can I make sure only the true value gets inserted?*" - by using `.then(…)` with a callback if you don't want to use `async`/`await`. You cannot access the value from the future immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `getData()` function returns a promise.  So you would need to either use `await` or use `.then` chain when calling `getData()`.  I suggest you use `await` if you can.  Make sure to declare you `baz` as `async` if you do:

```
async function baz() {
  //....
  document.getElementById('bar').textContent = await getData();
 //....
}
```

If you don't want to use `await`, call `then` like so:

```
function baz() {
  //....
  getData().then(data => {
     document.getElementById('bar').textContent = data;
  }

 //....
}
```

Comment: so then am I right in assuming I won't need the `then()` in the `getData()` function? It seems somewhat obsolete if I just use `then()` as you suggested

Comment: I mean, if I use `then()` like `getData().then()`, do I still need the `then()` inside `baz()` ?

Comment: Correct, would need to make sure that data transformation is handled in getData().then().